# Is $f$ concave at first argument

Tags: convex-analysis

Is $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$
with $f(x,y)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_j^3(y_j-x_j)$ concave in its first argument?

Answer (score 1):

Consider  $n=1$. Restrict  $f(x,y)=x^3y-x^4$ to the line $y=c$. Compute
$$ (x^3c-x^4)''= 6cx - 12x^2 \tag1$$
If $c\ne 0$, the right hand side of (1) changes sign at $0$.